# angular view not updating when checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

View not updating when checkbox is checked. Should I used $scope.$apply?
I need the `Current state` to change between YES and NO depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/murecugomi/1/edit?html,output) the code on JSbin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="notesApp">
  <head>
    <title>Notes App</title></head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
     <div>
       <h2>What are your favorite sports?</h2>
       <div ng-repeat="sport in ctrl.sports">
         <br/>
         <label ng-bind="sport.label"></label>

         <div>
           <input type="checkbox"
           ng-model="sport.selected"
           ng-true-value="YES"
           ng-false-value="NO">
         </div>


         <div>
           Current state: {{sport.selected}}
         </div>

       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the JS:

```
angular.module('notesApp', [])
 .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
   var self = this;
   self.sports = [
     {label: 'Basketball', selected: 'YES'},
     {label: 'Cricket', selected: 'NO'},
     {label: 'Soccer', selected: 'NO'},
     {label: 'Swimming', selected: 'YES'}
   ];

}]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add quotations because it's an angularjs expression and it also needs to be a constant. If YES is used for an angular expression normally angular would look for a scope variable named YES, but that's not going to be a constant angular expression as the value of YES could change.

Instead you want to just set the value to 'Yes' as you want to assign the value as the constant string 'YES'. If you looked in the console you would have seen: `Expected constant expression for 'ngTrueValue', but saw 'YES'`.

```
<input type="checkbox"
           ng-model="sport.selected"
           ng-true-value="'YES'"
           ng-false-value="'NO'"/>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ehXObXaXicC1BvKyQtmI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why I need to add the extra single quotation marks?

Comment: Short explanation of @Wayne Ellery's correct answer:You are manipulating with string, not with scoped object, instead of single quotation marks on "YES", you have to use it twice "'YES'" to scope it correctly for bind recognization.

Comment: Is it possible to add as $apply or $watch instead of the quotation twice? And how would that work?

Comment: You could but what is the issue of using quotations for 'YES', 'NO'? This is saying to set the value of sport.selected to 'YES' or 'NO' and that is what you want. Why would you like to use $apply or $watch? That seems a very complicated way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [constexpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/constexpr) in the Error Reference documentation from angularjs. It says

> Some attributes used in conjunction with ngModel (such as ngTrueValue or ngFalseValue) will only accept constant expressions.